# are there any homeomorphic pair of subsets?

Tags: general-topology

I need to know which of the following are homeomorphic pairs all are subsets of $\mathbb{R}^2$

$1$. $A=\{xy=0\}$

$2$. $B=\{x+y\ge 0,xy=0\}$

$3$ $C=\{xy=1\}$

$4$. $D=\{x+y\ge 0, xy=1\}$

I drew the pictures and concluded that None of them are.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$A$ is the set consisting of the two coordinate axes. $B$ is the set consisting of the two non-negative coordinate axes. $C$ is the graph of a hyperbola. No two of these three are homeomorphic:

- $A$ has a point, the origin, whose removal disconnects it into four components; neither $B$ nor $C$ has such a point.
- $B$ is homeomorphic to $\Bbb R$; removing any point disconnects it into two components.
- $C$ is homeomorphic to the disjoint union of two copies of $\Bbb R$: unlike $A$ and $B$, it is not connected.

$D$, however, is the half of $C$ that lies in the first quadrant; like $B$, it is homeomorphic to $\Bbb R$, so $B$ and $D$ are homeomorphic to each other.